# Is it possible to force to kill windows service using Octopus?

Tags: windows, windows-services, octopus-deploy

My octopus installs Windows Service in a machine, but sometimes it can't stop the service so it doesn't deploy.

If I manually go to the machine and try to stop the service, I can't. But if I first go to Task Manager and kill the process of the service, then I can stop the service.

Does Octopus already have a built-in feature to do this for me? Or should I create a .bat to execute it before reinstalling windows service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you import the step template [Stop Service With Kill](https://library.octopusdeploy.com/step-template/actiontemplate-stop-service-with-kill) you can add this as a deployment step.

The documentation [here](http://docs.octopusdeploy.com/display/OD/Step+Templates) provides a step by step way to do this

Answer (score 5):

Same to Ryan's process, we use the command in this format to kill process that would not gracefully shutdown

```
taskkill /im Processname /f
```

Just a note, this takes `Process Name` not `Service Name`, and all services share the same process name will be killed.

Answer (score 3):

You could try using a custom powershell pre-deployment script (enable the custom deployment scripts feature for your deployment step) or by placing this in a predeploy.ps1 file in your nuget package.

`kill -processname serviceName`